# How to make ubunu in power saver mode?

Tags: power-management

when i type this command in the terminal `sudo aptitude install pm-utils`
to use power saver mode it tells me `sudo:aptitude command not found`
what can I do to fix this ?

Answer (score 1):

We use `apt-get` for installing software in Ubuntu. So the command would be ...

```
sudo apt-get install pm-utils
```

Mind that pm-utils probably is already installed.

---

If you want to use aptitude you need to install that first. It is not installed by default (we have apt-get and Ubuntu Software Center as front-end).